How do I acquire the thread ID for a particular site?
Well, this is my site/page: https://avengersera.blogspot.com/2024/03/avengers.html
and I want to know what's the thread ID of it for using the API. Can anyone please help me with figuring it out?
I have searched it in the forums page of the site and found the forum ID. How can I find the thread ID? Also, is it the ID of a certain "discussion" in the forum?

click  Ctrl+u and search for 'postId' , this is   post Id for current post
